# WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param

Tags: django, fastcgi, wsgiserver

I'm currently trying to set up my first homepage using Django and have encountered some problems.

The server I've got my project on is running Django in FastCGI-mode and they have supplied me with a quick guide to set the settings I need to run Django, which looks something like this.

**mysite.fcgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/local/python
import sys, os

sys.path.append("/home/users/username")

from django.core.handler.wsgi import WSGIHandler
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

os.chdir("/home/users/username/mysite")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

WSGIServer(WSGIHandler()).run()
```

**.htaccess**

```
Addhandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I run **manage.py runfcgi** I get this message:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!-- The html from my main template --!>
```

Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Which web server you used, nginx , apache??

Comment: @GianfrancoLemmo - Sorry, forgot to mention that, I use apache